# Alamofire request parameter with double quote in string

Tags: swift, encoding, alamofire

I am facing wired scenario where I am passing parameter in request with double quote.

Using `JSONEncoding.default` Alamofire automatically escape the string with double quote with `\`  like

`"Test "hello "`  would be `"Test \" hello "`

But backhand wants me to send  `"Test \\\" hello "` (triple slash with double quote )

Is there any way to achieve this using `ParameterEncoding` or do I need to manually replace every string in parameter? I have a number of requests with hundreds of parameters in combination.

I have not added any code because it is simple alamofire request. Still, if you need to see it, I will update my question with alamofire request code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to customize the JSON encoding in this way, as this is a limitation of `JSONSerialization` and `JSONEncoder`. If this is truly a requirement, I would suggest creating your own `ParameterEncoding`  that handles this escaping for all encoded parameters.

```swift
final class EscapingJSONEncoder: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        guard let parameters = parameters else { return urlRequest }

        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

            if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
                urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            }

            urlRequest.httpBody = data
            urlRequest.httpBody = urlRequest.httpBody.map { data in
                var string = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\""#, with: #"\\\""#)

                return Data(string.utf8)
            }

        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }

        return urlRequest
    }


}
```

This is rather inefficient due to the `Data` -> `String` -> `Data` conversion, but it shouldn't be too bad for small payloads.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely try this  and will edit your answer with tested working code, Why you have downvoted question  Is there any reason , please let me know so I can update my question accordingly ?